# How is the stack organized? : Deleting a Binary Tree

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree, stack-trace

I have this code to remove a Binary Tree from memory but I don't know how the stack would look or how the recursion works when you make the recursive calls to `destroy(<#node* tree#>)`. I know that the recursion ends when you reach the end of a branch and so concludes that call and starts going up in the recursion, but if a recursive function call keeps where it left off, is the call to `destroy(tree->right)` waiting to be executed while `destroy(tree->left)` finishes?

```
struct node{
    int value;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};

void destroy(node* tree){
    if(tree != NULL){
        destroy(tree->left);
        destroy(tree->right);
        delete tree;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to grab a piece of paper to visualize it, but yes, they are sequential, do not have the same node in two places on the tree or you'll have problems.

it would go like

```
destroy(root)
>destroy(l)
    >l
         >l
         (...)
    >r
    (...)
>r
    >l
    (...)
    >r
    (...)
>delete root
>end
```

So you'll start pushing addresses upon addresses until you finally reach the end of the branch, then you pop once, and keep exploring until the end of the next branch and so on. Then finally, on the final branch, you'll pop all the functions until you are back to the original one, and delete the root node.

Comment: So it looks like in-order traversal? (and of course the deleting is the other way around)

Comment: The functon is post-order, it goes left, right, this, that is post order. The accessing goes pre-order but it doesnt matter until you actually do the operation on the node, so post-order it is: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal just check the pictures on the wiki article and follow the letters with your code

Answer (score 2):

destroy(tree->left) is fully executed before destroy(tree->right).

However, remember that left tree has both a left and a right side. So here it will again go all the way to the left first first and on the way back go to the right. The right may contain nodes at the left which are handled first.

The stack has little impact on this. Whenever you go one lever deeper into the tree (i.e. calling destroy on left or right), the function call may push a few variables to the stack - for instance a return address and the current node pointer. When a leaf is reached and the function calls starts returning, these variables are taken out of the stack again.

Normally this should not course problems but in case your tree has many levels, you might need to consider stack usage.

If you assume an empty stack to start with and look at the first call to destroy left, you will have:

stack = |first left|

Now this may cause another call to left:

stack = |first left| second left|

And even a third call to left:

stack = |first left| second left| third left|

Now the call to third left returns:

stack = |first left| second left|

But the right will be called:

stack = |first left| second left| first right |

This right may have a node on the left so we will get:

stack = |first left| second left| first right | first left |

and this will continue until all nodes returns - like this

stack = |first left| second left| first right |

stack = |first left| second left|

stack = |first left|

stack =

and now it is time to do the same from the top on the right side

stack = |first right|

and so on...

For the simple example in your code it will most likely result in a 4 byte return address being pushed to the stack for each level in the tree. So even with a rather deep tree level the stack usage will be low.